# Laravel pagination links are hidden

Tags: php, laravel, database, pagination

I am fetching some products from the database

```
    $products = Product::paginate(7);
    return view("products.index", compact("products"));
```

In the view I am doing this

```
$products->links()
```

but the main problem is that pagination links did not appear in the page. I thought that probably these links were no rendered... but they are rendered and for some reason they are set to hidden.

What is the reason? I have never faced this issue before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer.... I just published the pagination in vendor then changed the styling from there.